# Loading scripts in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm working on an angular app that is becoming quite large. At the moment I have several controllers, each controller is dependent upon different jquery plugins. Currently I'm loading all the scripts from my index.html file. I was wondering how I can load a specific script only to one controller using angular's router, and have angular load the script only upon arriving to the page, or if any other method is applicable to this scenario.

I found a tutorial that explains something similar, but I do not understand where she is loading the jquery script into the partial. (http://blog.ruedaminute.com/2012/02/angular-js-applying-jquery-to-a-loaded-partial/)

Thanks ahead

Comment: For starters your controllers are definitely not the place to reference your jQuery plugins or to do any kind of DOM manipulation; that should be handled inside a directive. See [here](http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/). In you directive you could then use [jQuery.getScript(function(){...});](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load your plugins, if need be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm gonna try out require.js for script loading....

Comment: Good call. Be sure to check out the Angular RequireJS seed project so: https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed/blob/master/app/js/main.js

Comment: Awesome now I know that one exists :)